# Changing TextInputEditText's select mode color

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

[image]

I am using TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText. I cant find a way to change this purple color. I searched about it too but i cant find so much. How can i change it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a little bit of styling to your app.

In `styles.xml` (or what is the name of your app's main theme file) you need to set `textInputStyle` for your app's theme:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.App.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Then you need to create a style for your `TextInputLayout` (in my case the parent style is `OutlinedBox` but you can choose any other style you want) and set `android:textColorHighlight` and `android:colorControlActivated` to your desired color. `textColorHighlight` sets the background color of selected text and `colorControlActivated` sets the color of two "holders" around the text:

```xml
<style name="Widget.App.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox" parent="Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#00ff00</item>
</style>
```

And after these manipulations you'll see the following result:

[image: Themed selection controls]

Comment: Thanks but android:colorControlActivated is not working. Its still purple...

Comment: Which Android version you use for test?